# MasterPage, how to avoid calling the same operations?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page that represents a members section. In order to gain access to it, you must log in.

I have a couple more asp.net pages that use that master page.
In each one of them, I have a call to a function that checks whether the user is logged in. If not, he is redirected to the homepage.

Can I implement that call in the master page, and not in each one of the child pages? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, move the call from the Page_Load of the page... to the Page_Load of the master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BasePage class and derive all page from that. For example:

```
class BasePage : System.Web.Page
{
    protected bool IsUserLoggedIn { get { /* ... */ } }
    protected void RedirectToLogin()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

class Home : BasePage
{
    /* ... */
}
```